# HTML5 draggable changing position of droppable areas

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using native HTML5 functionality draggable.

What is causing me problems is that droppable elements (areas where draggable can be dropped - yellow DIVs) are changing position when drop is made.

What I've already tried is to make draggable element position:absolute, but then draggable elements are overlapping.

Any idea how to solve this? I would like to have draggable elements (blue DIV) stacked, but when they are dragged into yellow DIVS, yellow ones must remain their position.

```js
function StartDrag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function Drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function DragOver(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.div1{
  position:relative;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 15px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.div2{  
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: blue;  
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
}

.div3{
  position:relative;
  margin: 15px;
  padding:15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="div1" ondrop="Drop(event)" ondragover="DragOver(event)">

  

</div>
<div id="div2" class="div1" ondrop="Drop(event)" ondragover="DragOver(event)"></div>




<div id="divDraggableElements" class="div3" ondrop="Drop(event)" ondragover="DragOver(event)">
  <div id="divD1" class="div2" draggable="true" ondragstart="StartDrag(event);"></div>
  <div id="divD2" class="div2" draggable="true" ondragstart="StartDrag(event);"></div>
  <div id="divD3" class="div2" draggable="true" ondragstart="StartDrag(event);"></div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give in class

```
.div1{ 
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Hope this works.